# Counting the number of trainable parameters in a gradient boosted tree

Tags: decision-trees, xgboost, boosting, bagging

I recently ran the gradient boosted tree regressor using scikit-learn via:

> GradientBoostingRegressor()

This model depends on the following hyperparameters:

- Estimators ($N_1$)
- Min Samples Leaf ($N_2$)
- Max Depth ($N_3$)
  which in-turn determine the number of trainable parameters in this model.  My question is, how can I count the number of parameters (trainable or otherwise randomly assigned) which determined the final model as a function of the above?

My guess is $N_1 \times N_2 \times N_3$ but is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe that can be the size of your grid, but not the number of possible trainable  hyperparameter of the [Gradient Boosting Regressor of scikit learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor.html).

I add some more hyperparameters of GBDT Regressor:

- loss{‘ls’, ‘lad’, ‘huber’, ‘quantile’},
- learning_rate
- criterion{‘friedman_mse’, ‘mse’, ‘mae’}
- max_features{‘auto’, ‘sqrt’, ‘log2’},

This is just some of the hyperparameters needed, this is extracted from the documentation
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor.html